# Need to troubleshoot a workflow

Tags: maximo

I am coming into an existing SCCD project and there is a custom field that is maintained between the Service Request and Incident forms. The problem is that the field is not being carried over properly. I suspect this is an issue within the workflow? Is there a proper way to debug or search for this problem area? So far, I've been poking around the 500+ workflow items for each the Service Request and Incident objects.

Comment: I don't use SR, but you'd have to look at the .class files, cross over domains, or whatever method they use to transfer data over to the other module. Sometimes, it is a matter of just adding a field to cross over domain, other times you need to create your own process (e.g. automation script), or modify the .class file. Can you be more specific as to what the field is, what module it is in, where it is going... and what command you use to get to transfer from the user interface (UI).

Comment: Looking into the domain application did the trick! I'm quite new to SCCD/Maximo, and just needed to stop looking at workflows. Can you post an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks a zillion, you just saved my estimate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into a similar situation where a custom field in the work order table was transfer over when we duplicated the work order. In that case, we had to look for the domain responsible for passing specific fields to be included in the duplication. It was a matter of adding the new custom field (dept) to the domain entry.

Other times, you may have to create an automation script, or modify the Java .class file (decode, rewrite, and recompile).

Comment: Thanks so much!!For other issues, where are these class files typically? I have found some of the compiled beans, but no source file within the WebSphere/Maximo directories?

Comment: The .class files are in your Maximo.ear ... The .class are typically called when accessing specific modules, or certain fields. If you go to database configuration, you'll see many .class files are referenced. And also object structures with inbound/outbound processes. They are all over...

Comment: I've seen the references everywhere, but could never find the actual source. Is the Maximo.ear a package of Java classes?

Comment: This will explain maximo.ear for you: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/tivoli_iea/com.ibm.iea.mam/mam/7.1/sys_install_deployment/build_deploy_Maximo_EAR/player.html